# Include additional fields with Person Site Column

Tags: user-profile, lookup-column, custom-list

When I create a column of type Lookup, there is a section at the bottom labeled "Add a column to show each of these additional fields:"  I want to do this same thing with a Person column.

It seems like this should be possible, per the MSDN [SPFieldUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduser.aspx) inherits from SPFieldLookup.  The [Field Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580.aspx) indicates that `User` is a specialized `Lookup`.

Is this possible?

I've thought about adding Text columns to my list, then creating a workflow to populate the values.  However, if the user profile is updated after the workflow runs, then my list will be out of date.

I really don't care if these values are on my list forms, but I need to be able to display them on a view.

Answer (score 0):

Although SPFieldUser does inherit from SPFieldLookup and it really is a lookup field to the hidden "Users" list I don't think there is any way to display those additional fields via the UI.

The workflow idea will work as long as you make sure to trigger the workflow when an item is added and when an item is changed.

Another option would be to create a custom query for your view that will join to the Users list. This may not be trivial though as there is not much for documentation on the Users list.